# Xpath - How to select an element that contains a text but nothing more

Tags: xpath

I am trying to select an element that contains a piece of text but I do not want to select the elements that contain the text plus additional text. I would normally use `text()='abc def'`, but this particular element contains spaces before and after.

Here is an example snippet:

```
<div> 
     <div>
          abc def
     </div>
     <div>
          abc def ghi
     </div>
     <div>
          abc def ghi jkl
     </div>
</div>
```

I want to select the first div but `//div[text()='abc def']` does not work because of the leading spaces and `//div[contains(text(),'abc def']` also does not work because it will select all of the divs.

I have looked into `normalize-space` and `starts-with`, but I could not get it to quite work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this?

```
//div[normalize-space()='abc def']/text()
```

Comment: This worked! I didn't try normalize-space()='abc def' and was using normalize-space('abc def')

Answer (score 0):

`'//div/div[normalize-space(text())="abc def"]'`